# import multiple image from two column

Tags: magento-1.9, php, xml, csv

i want import this in my magento, this csv have two columns of image, now how import this on my store:

### this is a csv example:

http://www.filedropper.com/importproduct

i read some guide but this guide require a image file in the same column,
example this:

```
image_label1, _image2, image_3, image4, imgage5
```

in my csv the image have two colums.

Comment: what are you using to import the csv, magento import or magento dataflow profiles?

Comment: I have no preference for one or the other

Answer (score 3):

If you use magento dataflow profiles you can create a csv in which the first row has the names of the product attributes (there are some mandatory columns you must complete, ie: sku, attribute_set, type, etc)

So you can create a csv like this:

```
sku, attribute_set, type, image, small_image, alt_image_one, alt_image_two, alt_image_three
```

then the images you want to upload should be located in media/import, so lets say you have this row:

**SKU1, some_attribute_set, simple, csvimport/sku1_image.jpg, csvimport/sku1_small_image.jpg, etc**

Then the images should be in here **media/import/csvimport/**

Comment: the photo is located in external domain, so i can not upload the photo in media/import/csvimport/